# How to make some function parameter optional without default value and others with default value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote a function

```js
function patchItem = (id: string | number, data: object, params: object = {}, cancelToken?: CancelToken, additionalDispatchData: object = {})
{

}
```

Here I want to make `params`, `cancelToken` and `additionalDispatchData`  parameters optional, but don't want to give `cancelToken` an initial value.

The above definition not showing any errors in typescript and compiling perfectly.

Above code is compiling in the following js code

```
function patchItem = (id, data, params = {}, cancelToken, additionalDispatchData = {})
{

}
```

But here in JS, the `cancelToken` is not optional and I think a mandatory parameter cannot exist in between the two optional parameters as above.

One way I find out is making `cancelToken` optional by giving `undefined` value as default and remove the question mark.

But I want to know if this is the bug in `tsc`, that it should have given `undefined` as the default value to `cancelToken` in compiled JS or I'm doing some kind of mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But here in JS, the `cancelToken` is not optional and I think a mandatory parameter cannot exist in between the two optional parameters as above.

In JavaScript, **all** parameters are optional.

> But I want to know if this is the bug in `tsc`, that it should have given `undefined` as the default value to `cancelToken` in compiled JS or I'm doing some kind of mistake here?

None of the above. :-) By default, all parameters to a JavaScript function are optional and have a default value of `undefined` if no default is provided. The only difference between:

```
function foo(arg = undefined) { }
```

and

```
function foo(arg) { }
```

is that `foo`'s *arity* (the number of parameters it expects) as expressed by `foo.length` will be `0` in the first case and `1` in the second case. That's literally the only difference.

It's important to distinguish between JavaScript/TypeScript optional parameters (and TypeScript's function overloading) vs. function overloading as it's handled in other languages like C# or Java. In JavaScript and TypeScript, if you want to allow people to *leave off* arguments that aren't at the end of the parameter list, you have to handle shuffling the arguments around yourself.

Consider this simpler example:

```
function foo(a: string, n?: number, o?: object): void
{
  console.log(a, n, o);
}

foo("one", 1, {});
foo("two", {}); // Error: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3F%3A%20number%2C%20o%3F%3A%20object)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(a%2C%20n%2C%20o)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Afoo(%22two%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%7B%7D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'number'.))*

Notice that you can't just leave off the `n` parameter. You have to do this:

```
foo("two", undefined, {});
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3F%3A%20number%2C%20o%3F%3A%20object)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(a%2C%20n%2C%20o)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Afoo(%22two%22%2C%20undefined%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B))*

If you use TypeScript's function overloading, it will allow you to leave off the middle argument from a type perspective, but your implementation has to handle shuffling the actual received parameter values around:

```
function foo(a: string, n: number, o: object): void;
function foo(a: string, o: object): void;
function foo(a: string, n?: any, o?: object): void
{
  if (typeof n === "object") {
    o = n;
    n = undefined;
  }
  console.log(a, n, o);
}

foo("one", 1, {}); // "one", 1, {}
foo("two", {});    // "two", undefined, {}
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3A%20number%2C%20o%3A%20object)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20o%3A%20object)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3F%3A%20any%2C%20o%3F%3A%20object)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20n%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22object%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20o%20%3D%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20n%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20console.log(a%2C%20n%2C%20o)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D%0D%0Afoo(%22two%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22two%22%2C%20undefined%2C%20%7B%7D))*

If you had the overloads but *didn't* do the shuffling in the implementation, you'd end up with `n` referencing an object and `o` having `undefined`:

```
// Incorrect
function foo(a: string, n: number, o: object): void;
function foo(a: string, o: object): void;
function foo(a: string, n?: any, o?: object): void
{
  console.log(a, n, o);
}

foo("one", 1, {}); // "one", 1, {}
foo("two", {});    // "two", {}, undefined
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3A%20number%2C%20o%3A%20object)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20o%3A%20object)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20n%3F%3A%20any%2C%20o%3F%3A%20object)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(a%2C%20n%2C%20o)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22one%22%2C%201%2C%20%7B%7D%0D%0Afoo(%22two%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22two%22%2C%20undefined%2C%20%7B%7D))*

This all stems from the fact that the static type information doesn't exist at runtime, and there's really only **one** function.

(It would be *possible* for TypeScript to output `foo("two", undefined, {})` when you write `foo("two", {})` in your code and it knows that it only matches the second overload signature, but that's a step beyond what the TypeScript designers are currently willing to have it do. :-) )